# Is it possible to update macOS without Apple ID?

Tags: macos, software-update

I don't really like an idea of using an Apple ID and want to refrain from it. Is there a way to update macOS without registering into the Mac App Store?

Comment: The steps to do this vary. What version of macOS do you want to update and be clear that update means security and patches within a major release and upgrade means running a major version installer.

Comment: It's worth saying that an AppleID is at its simplest just a user account, and no different from logging into anywhere with a username and password. If you want to use the Mac App Store, then you'll need to have one. There's no reason to fear having one for basic usage, even from the most paranoid point of view.

Comment: @benwiggy AppleID requires a phone number, which is very different from username and password. There are real reasons for protecting ones PII, both from misuse as well as irresponsible data breaches. Unfortunately, Apple does not care about protecting their users PII, otherwise, they would not ask for cell phone number. OTP would work just fine with auth for added security.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are three ways to update macOS without using an Apple ID. Most important thing to remember is that a user only needs the Mac App Store to download the installer, which downloads the update to the machine.

You can also download the installer from the Web by visiting [this](https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos) link on Apple Support website. Then copy the installer to the Applications folder. Double click on the application and you will be able to install the update.

---

*Update since Big Sur*

For macOS 11 & later Apple no longer provide access via the earlier Downloads link. You need to either get them via this Apple KB link - [How to download and install macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT211683) which will handoff to the App Store, then Software Update. I cannot test whether it will allow you to access without an Apple ID, I don't have any Mac not associated.

Alternatively, use [Two Canoes' MDS](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/) [freeware] which skips the App Store entirely.

Comment: While it does hand off to the App Store, the App Store doesn't actually handle the download - it just opens the System Settings. No login prompt is shown.