# Upgrading to Ventura without AppleId

Tags: macos, apple-id, upgrade

I am considering upgrading to Ventura. However, I do not have or need an AppleId.

Will the upgrade proceed relatively uneventful without an AppleId? Note, I have become aware from online technical articles that certain apps that require AppleId (Pages), though free, may not work.

Are there any articles from reputable sources that have performed upgrade to Ventura without AppleId?

Comment: Installing macOS doesn't have anything to do with an AppleID.  The OS will ask you for one, and offer to set one up for you, but you are free to ignore.

Comment: As @MarcWilson says, but you will need an AppleID if you want to install apps from the Apple App Store, even free apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to update macOS without Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321774/is-it-possible-to-update-macos-without-apple-id) Also, when you'll want to download apps, you'll need an Apple ID (as mentioned by Gilby), you'll notice that soon enough.

Comment: I've updated the linked duplicate with information which has changed since Big Sur. The older download site no longer carries macOS, after Catalina.

Comment: You can use Pages without an AppleID - but you can't acquire it, as you need to have one to use the Mac App Store.